# Prove $e^{x}$ is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x} = \infty$. I have already shown that $e^{x}$ is monotone increasing so the best way I think is to use monotone convergence theorem.

The only problem is showing $e^{x}$ is unbounded. I try with contradiction:

Suppose $e^{x}$ were bounded. Then there exists $B$ so that $|e^{x}| < B$ for all $x$. Now I just need help finding a contradiction.

If we multiply each side of the inequality by $|e^{-x}|$ we get $1 < B|e^{-x}|$. But since $|e^{-x}|$ is always positive, the right-hand side is also just $Be^{-x}
$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the first two terms of the series we get $e> 1 +\frac1{1!}=2$. Now write every number in base 2 system. Then $e^n> 2^n$ has more than $n$ digits (or 'bits'). As $n\to\infty$ we see that  we cannot bound $e^n$ by any number $B$, as $B$ would have fixed number of binary digits.

Answer (score 4):

We can easily show by induction that

$$e^n>n$$

and from here deduce the result by squeeze theorem.

Comment: but that just shows it is not bounded above, right?

Comment: Yes that’s right. For the other bounding we have that $e^x>0$.